# работа с dynamic в c#

Tags: c#

допустим есть две таблицы в базе:
первая таблица содержит колонки

```
Id, Alias, Title
```

и в ней имеются записи:

```
1 | "SiteSettings" | "Настройки сайта", ...
```

вторая таблица содержит колонки

```
Id, ParentId, Alias, Title, Value, ValueType
```

содержимое таблицы вида:

```
1 | 1 | "AllowRegistration" | "Разрешить регистрацию" | "True", "System.Boolean", ...
```

На старте приложения формируется статический кеш, в него добавляется переменная

```
dynamic Settings
```

*(Возможно вместо dynamic следует использовать что-то другое?)*

Ну и собственно сам вопрос:
Можно ли получить на выходе нечто подобное:

```
Settings.SiteSettings.AllowRegistration
```

И если можно, то как?

Comment: > Возможно вместо dynamic следует использовать что-то другое - да, в этом случае стоит использовать обычные строготипизированные классы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решенье найдено на просторах англоязычного ресурса стэка:

для начала делаем екстеншен для **ExpandoObject**:

```
public static class ExpandoExt
{
   public static KeyValuePair<string, object> WithValue(this string key, object value)
   {
       return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key, value);
   }

   public static ExpandoObject Init(this ExpandoObject expando, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] values)
   {
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in values)
       {
          ((IDictionary<string, Object>)expando)[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
       }
       return expando;
   }
}
```

Далее:

```
using (var repo = new SettingRepository())
{
    IList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> obj = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
    foreach (var section in repo.Collection)
    {
        obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(section.Alias, section.Value));
    }
    _settings = ((ExpandoObject)_settings).Init(obj.ToArray());
 }
```

и вуаля, конструкция `_settings.чего-то_там_из_базы` работает.
может кому тоже пригодится
[ссылка на английский сабж](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910331/how-can-i-use-collection-initializer-syntax-with-expandoobject)

**UPD**: тоесть на практике можно все свести к конструкции:

```
...
foreach (var section in repo.Collection)
{
   ((IDictionary<string, object>)_settings)[section.Alias]=section.Value;
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на то, что в этом случае можно использовать `dynamic`, более *надежным* способом будет объявить два обычных класса `Settings` и `SiteSettings`.

`dynamic` стоит применять только в случае, когда без них писать код оказывается мучительно больно:

- работа с COM
- взаимодействие с динамическими языками (например, с IronPython)

Если в конкретном случае вместо `dynamic` *можно* создать конкретный класс - то его *стоит* создать.

Comment: беда в том, что заранее неизвестно какие настройки есть в базе, но с ними было бы неплохо работать как с ViewBag например.

Comment: тоесть я имею ввиду что конструкция вида `Settings.SiteSettings.AllowRegistration` должна получиться динамически

Comment: @Dmitry если вам *заранее неизвестно*, какие настройки есть, то в коде вы их как `Settings.SiteSettings.AllowRegistration` упоминать не можете. А если вы все-таки знаете заранее (в момент написания кода), что есть настройка `SiteSettings.AllowRegistration` - то что вам мешает использовать обычный класс?

Comment: @Dmitry я к тому, что если вам в коде обращение к настройкам в виде строки `Settings.SiteSettings.AllowRegistration` не нужно, то вам и динамики не нужны. хватит обычного `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: Это будет отдельная Dll код который оутсорсерам передаваться не будет, но оутсорсный верстальщик к примеру мог бы использовать нормализованный вид а не гинерики. Собственно идея такова, что некто насоздвал настроек через админку, а верстальщик это с легкостью применил

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic settings= new ExpandoObject();;
settings.SiteSettings= new ExpandoObject();
settings.SiteSettings.AllowRegistration = false
```

Comment: Вероятно не верно понят вопрос, конструкция `settings.SiteSettings.AllowRegistration` заранее не известна, ее хотелось бы иметь динамически