# Динамические поля у cущности

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

С C# занимаюсь относительно недавно. С простыми классами (моделями) более менее понятно. Стоит задача организовать модели и логику по следующим таблицам:

```
Nomenclature:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nomenclature](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [InvNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvBuh] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [TypeN] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MOL] [int] NULL,
    [TH] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Nomenclature] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Как реализовать в классах различный набор полей (которые хранятся в других таблицах в виде списка полей и списка их значений) у сущности (модели)  `Nomenclature` в зависимости от двух полей `[TypeN]`, `[TH]`. Т.е. для каждого варианта `[TypeN]+[TH]` у `Nomenclature` должны быть свои поля в дополнении к общим перечисленным в указанной таблице. Уже голову сломал, не могу сообразить как это реализовать. Перерыл весь интернет, но подробного примера нигде не нашел. Наследование не подойдет, так как список дополнительных полей может меняться. Нужно динамическое создание полей у сущности. База SQL+EF+ADO.NET+Code First

Никто с таким не сталкивался?

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вам такое? Какой объект реальности вы этим моделируете? Расскажите подробнее.

Comment: Ну и допустим, что вы умудрились в рантайме динамически создать поля. Как по-вашему должен выглядеть код, который с этими полями работает? (Учитывая, что вы на этапе компиляции не знаете ни названий полей, ни их типов.)

Comment: Номенклатура. Есть общие поля инвентарный номер, название, модель, и т.д.. Но у каждого вида номенклатуры есть свои дополнительные характеристики, которые в свою очередь вводятся пользователем. В 1С есть такое, но стоит задача реализовать это в C# проекте. вот уже голову сломал, как это сделать. Название полей можно получать и с таблиц из названий характеристик переводя  в латиницу (или нумеровать) Field001 (Field + Id поля в справочнике списка характеристик)...

Comment: А зачем вам именно классы? Если вы всё равно не можете к ним получить доступ времени компиляции. Почему не `Dictionary<string, object>`, `ExpandoObject` или что-то подобное?

Comment: Если под моделью подразумевается что-то типа таблицы из БД, то нужно организовывать еще одну таблицу типа `custom_field`. И связывать ее отношениями many-to-many с основной. Странно, что ничего не нашли, практика распространенная. В шарпе это будет еще один класс.

Comment: Со стороны таблиц понятно Custom_field... если они предопределенные... Вопрос как их добавлять как свойства к объектам, выводить соответственно их на форму, делать их валидацию и обработку изменений..... Если попробовать только custom_field делать как ExpandoObject

Comment: @АлександрШкробов, почитайте мой вопрос с моим же ответом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460996/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-dynamic-%D0%B2-c уже делал подобное, не совсем так как у вас в вопросе, но можно доработать, главное это то, что на выходе хотите получить вы

Comment: @VladD Entity Framework не умеет работать с `Dictionary<string, object>` или `ExpandoObject`

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну да, но EF требует знания структуры объекта в compile time.

Comment: @VladD так у автора наверняка именно в этом проблема и заключалась

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу, судя по всему, от EF придётся отказаться :-\ Впрочем, в любом случае не вижу, как с EF разрулить динамические поля.

Answer (score 7):

### Вариант 1.

Используйте подход EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value)

Будет как-то так:

```
public class Entity {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public virtual Collection<Value> Values {get; set;}
}

public class Attribute {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Value {
  [Key, Column(Order=0)]
  public long EntityId {get; set;}
  [Key, Column(Order=1)]
  public long AttributeId {get; set;}

  public virtual Attribute Attribute {get; set;}
  public virtual Entity Entity {get; set;}

  public object Value {get; set;}
}
```

Ну и в БД соответственно - три таблицы.

### Вариант 2.

Выкиньте из вашей связки EF и используйте простой ADO.NET. Такие классы, как DataRow и DataTable, прекрасно умеют хранить произвольное число столбцов.

### Дополнение

Если поля очень-очень динамические, есть смысл использовать NoSQL-базы. Или просто храните в базе xml либо json.